# Using Python requests to upload a file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm working on a program to automate uploading a file to a website. I'd like it to take some image file from the user, and then upload it to a specific website by clicking a `Choose File` button, selecting the file from disk, then pressing select. The HTML for the button looks like this:

```
<form action="/api" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      FILE: <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm very new to web programming, but from my understanding this sort of thing can be done with requests. How would I go about it?

Comment: Do you want use requests send a file?

Comment: Well, the website I'm working with basically takes an image file, modifies it, and then allows the user to download the modified version. It has something like this to upload the file with: http://puu.sh/miAvM/2522c0dadf.png
So if that qualifies as sending a file, then yes.

Comment: Yes I know, then please check that duplicate question.